# During state change in React, is it possible to append values to URL

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering, if, on state change, I can add something like this to URL

`www.abc.com/?state=on`

without page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `History.replaceState()` in useEffect to change url when state changing

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.history.replaceState(
        history.state,
        null,
        `?state=${state}`
    );
}, [state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/',
  search: '?state=on'
})
```

You can use history.push and don't worry about your page reload.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `useNavigate` hook to navigate to any path you'd want to (This is available from react-router-v6 onwards, if you are using an older version, consider using `useHistory`). This doesn't cause any page reloads, further using `useParams` you could also extract the param values to make necessary computations in the target component.

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
//OR
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom' //Prior to react-router-v6

export default function Component(props){ 
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  //OR
  const history = useHistory()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    history.push({pathname:'/',
     search:'?state=on'
    })
    //OR
    navigate({
     pathname:'/',
     search:'?state=on'},{replace:false}) //Set replace=true if you'd want to disable back navigation, false otherwise.
  }, [state]);

  //REST OF THE COMPONENT LOGIC
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I suggest you check out the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial) of react router for more information.